# Accessing SQL Aliases with PHP

Tags: php, sql, alias

This code works to give me what I want in my phpMyAdmin server:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT salesperson, units, profit, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS position
FROM sales AS t ORDER BY profit DESC;
```

The problem happens when I transfer this to php:

```
<?php 
    
$sql = "SELECT salesperson, units, profit, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS position\n"
. "FROM sales AS t ORDER BY profit DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        echo $row['salesperson'] . " " . $row['units'] . " " . $row['profit'] .$row['position'] . "<br>";
}
```

It outputs the first three rows but not the fourth. The alias created with SQL.

Comment: What does `var_export($row)` show? And why's there no `SET` query passed to DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you choose not exactly the best way to debug your output. Stringifying `$row['position']` directly (by piping it into `echo`) hides a lot of useful info that you would be able to find otherwise.

Second, the query in your second snippet misses actually setting up that variable, like this:

```
$sql = <<<QUERY
  SELECT salesperson, units, profit, 
         (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS position
  FROM sales AS t, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS r
  ORDER BY profit DESC
QUERY;

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "$row[salesperson] $row[units] $row[profit] $row[position]<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raina77ow this got the coding producing what I wanted. With your help I can see where I went wrong. I will need to study more to understand why. Many thanks again for your help. Regards Alan

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, in the latest version of MySQL (8.0+) [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) are finally supported which avoids the use of `@` session variables. Doing so you can also add row numbers by group with `PARTITION BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT salesperson
       , units
       , profit
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY profit DESC) AS `overall_position`
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY salesperson
                           ORDER BY profit DESC) AS `salesperson_position`
FROM sales
ORDER BY profit DESC
```

Comment: Yes, that's cleaner if DB supports it. Window functions are also supported by MariaDB ([since 10.2](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/introduction-to-window-functions-in-mariadb-server-10-2/)).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to contribute your solution Parfait. At this time this solution is beyond my understanding but it will provide food for thought and developing my understanding further in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Understood @AlanTaylor. But if you have MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.2+, consider learning and implementing window functions (`ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()`, any aggregate). Correlated subqueries and session variables for row number/counts and ranks can be more confusing and inefficient. Sadly, MySQL and MariaDB are latecomers in supporting window functions ([SQL:2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003)) and even [CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) ([SQL:1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999))! We all start as newcomers! Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I will, as I am sure it will help with the next evolution of my project. Having used the above code and Pagination to divide the data into a series of tables, first 10 records then the next 10 and so one. I am researching away to search these tables for a name, which is the easy bit. Then showing that table with the name highlighted and the position in that table. From my limited understanding of your remarks, your approach would help with that.  Thanks again.